# HTML5 sidebar syntax

Tags: html5, gui

I am trying to learn how to write clean HTML5 code and I came across a sidebar.

I need to get something like this:

[image]

My code:

```html
<aside>
<section>
    <header>
        <h1>Naujienos</h1>
    </header>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h3>2015-09-20</h3>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="image/zagiena-plius.gif" alt="zagienaplius">
                    </figure>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h3>2013-10-30</h3>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="image/mes-rusiuojam.gif" alt="mes-rusiuojam">
                    </figure>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
</aside>
```

Am I going in the right direction? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: The way you do it is not wrong. Just some minor things (I don't think they deserve to be an answer): Don't use a list, normal `<article>` tags should suffice, else use `<div>`, unless you want ordinals in front of the date (check your code in your post by pressing the button). You may now continue with CSS styling. HTML is not meant for styling and thus you need to take a look at what you want to achieve and use meaningful CSS classes where needed.

Comment: I had the idea of code without the list but I saw it in [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/) , "the layouts body" section so I figured I should be using list also. So it does not matter if I use `<article>` or `<div>` without list ? Yeah, once I will be done with HTML I will carry on with CSS

Comment: It really doesn't matter because things like `<article>` or `<div>` are usually already ordered like you want and also don't share lines, ie. inherit a line-break (just tested to confirm).

Comment: Could you upload the images with imgur? We can't see them, and it seems a little important to the review.

Comment: @Laurel I uploaded the image.

Comment: Can you give more details about what this content is / represents? I don’t understand the purpose of the sidebar, so deciding which markup would be appropriate is not possible.

Comment: @unor well this sidebar basically is a simple news section. It displays news related to the company. Sorry for non-english language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aside` element already creates a section, there is no need for an additional `section` element.

If you use `h1` for the `aside` element’s heading, the headings in the `article` elements should be `h2` instead of `h3` (or also `h1`, but that’s not recommended).

But using `article` for these short snippets might not be a good idea in the first place (unless they will contain more than just a date and an image), because each `article` also creates a section.

For the date you should use the `time` element.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Did not know that I should not skip `h` tags that they should be used in order. Instead of `article` I should use `div` or something else ?

Comment: @Tomeister: If the sidebar contains news, and each news post maybe has a teaser, and/or an image, and/or a link to the full post, then `article` seems to be appropriate. But if it’s mostly just a line of text, or just a title and a link to the full post, a simple list (`ul`) seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: ok I see, I will have that in mind. Thanks